# How to change Windows 8 Start Background Image and Color Scheme?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I want to change the style of the Windows 8 Start Screen:

[image]

Under `Charmsbar > Settings > More PC Settings > Personalize > Start Screen` you can choose out of 20 predefined background images and between 25 predefined color schemes:

[image]

How can you specify your own custom Windows 8 Start Background Image and Color Scheme? There were multiple Tools for the preview version like *Windows 8 UI Tweaker* or *My WCP Start Screen Customizer*, however none of them seem to work in the final release version of Windows 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ModernBack Changer](http://pasquiindustry.deviantart.com/art/ModernBack-changer-2-8-31-10-2012-333789315):

[image]

It works with Windows 8 RTM and lets you change both the background and accent color.

Answer (score 5):

There are no applications for the final release yet, the Accent settings are found under:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent

If you feel like hacking around...