# Windows 8 UI tweaks

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change Windows 8 Start Background Image and Color Scheme?](https://superuser.com/questions/466043/how-to-change-windows-8-start-background-image-and-color-scheme)

The Windows 8 Start Screen has a variety of color options, and a limited set of background images that can be selected.

Is there a way to add a custom Image to that set of background images?  I'd imagine I'd have to make a set of them, one for each of the color variants, but I'm not sure if I can "plug into" that area of the settings.

Thanks!