# How to make custom Windows 8 start screen color scheme?

Tags: windows-8

I thought it would be fun and nice to brand start screen with the colors of our company's logo by customizing the color scheme of the start screen.

*Windows 8 Start screen:*
[image: start screen]

First I found the tool [decor8](http://www.stardock.com/products/decor8/) mentioned [here](http://betanews.com/2012/11/09/customize-the-windows-8-start-screen-with-stardocks-decor8/), but it costs money and that's not an option.
Then I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/466043/how-to-change-windows-8-start-background-image-and-color-scheme) solution here on the site. But when I read the comments about if its safe I began thinking it would be safer to do it by yourself and not with a third party tool.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 has the native ability to change Start Screen backgrounds, i.e., selecting from a handful of preset patterns and colors. Although the ability is pretty limited in terms of choices that the user is presented with, in terms of say using Decor8 as you mentioned above.

You can do that by heading to the Personalize menu in Settings, selecting the second tab that says Start screen, and making the changes as per your choosing. The screenshot below illustrates your options in this regard.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I know how to chose one of the built in. I also had a picture of the color scheme selector. But I want to make my own custom color scheme.

Comment: @Tim Hi, your best option is Decor8 which I know you are aware of